# Notification that user accepted friend request

Tags: php, html

I am making a website with friendship system. 'Friends' table looks like this:

```
id | id1(this is sender) | id2 | accepted | notification
```

id1 is guy who sends the request. When id2 accepts it, accepted and notification will be 1. Notification means that user with id1 will see a notification: 
User (with id2) accepted your request. I want to change notification to 0 when user with id1 click on that notification. I do all actions by making a form with action "`something.php`". I think there is a better way to change just one column (in row), than doing it as I am doing.

What method should I use?
What methods are possible?

Comment: *"than doing it as i am doing"* which is...?

Comment: i would make a button refering to "notification.php" and in that i would make $sql that updates table and query it. But as i said i want to know other ways to do it. I think there is some better way

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should consider using AJAX to call your "something.php" in the background.

Doing that using a form means that when a user sees the notification will get the whole page reloaded. Using AJAX this won't happen.

See the link below:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/AJAX

Using jQuery it should look something like this

```
$('#notification').onClick( function(){
    $.ajax({
        type: "post",
        data: {},
        url: "something.php",

        success: function(){
             //do something like clearing notification on frontend
        }
    });
});
```